# Layout with 2 LinearLayout with screen width each one

Tags: xml, android

I'm trying to create something similar to what fragments allow we to do but without fragments.

I'm trying to create one layout (relative or linear, I dont know wich one to use and how to make it, that where I need some help) and put another 3 LinearLayout inside it.

Each one of 3 LinearLayouts should have the screen width, I'm trying to make it with xml, without code, since when I tried to use code to resize layouts i got a lot of trouble because of layouts not measured at onCreate.

Then I'll set a touchListener to the big layout and create something similar to fragments.

Can someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

> "I'm trying to create something similar to what fragments allow we to
>   do but without fragments."

Fragments have their own lifecycle and are a "modular section of an activity." The big idea with them is that you can re-use portions of an activity in different configurations. They are far more powerful than nested layouts (or views with touch listeners that you plan to switch between, like ViewSwitcher?). I wouldn't try to re-create fragments, just use fragments?

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

> "I'm trying to create one layout (relative or linear, I dont know wich
>   one to use and how to make it, that where I need some help) and put
>   another 3 LinearLayout inside it."

I am not sure I understand the question, but either relative or linear layouts can contain other layouts. One simple example (NOTE that this is NOT necessarily an efficient layout, it's just an example of nesting them per the question):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#cccccc"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="ONE" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#dddddd"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TWO" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#696969"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="THREE" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This creates the following in a typical Window (Activity):

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry for not studying enough for knowing how powerful fragments are, I'm sure that they are good on what they're supposed to do and I'm sure that I'm not close to know everything they can do, but I'm learning =). I don't want to use fragments because I'm trying to do something that will run in every version of android.

actually i want to do something like you did but the top linearlayout should be horizontal and not vertical, then I want to be able to scroll this big layout and change to the other ones that will fill the screen, can you understand me now?

thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Fragments are pretty cool, and not that hard to learn. Also, they work with just about every Android version you might need to support via the support library, which is also easy to use (http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Using). Still, Fragments aren't needed unless you plan to re-use parts of activities in different layouts, like on a phone in portrait one way, and on a tablet in landscape another way. In those cases though (most apps), they come in super handy.